# Go Into Stalemate

Tags: word-choice, phrasal-verbs, licensing

Some usage of "*go into*" allows this sentence:

> The company ***went into*** bankruptcy.

Could "*go into*", then, be used like this:

> The two teams ***went into*** stalemate.

where the context is sports?

Also, is "*go into stalemate*" usual?

Answer (score 1):

Google N-grams does not record 'go into stalemate', 'go into a stalemate', 'went into stalemate' or 'went into a stalemate'.

'[reach] a stalemate' is more common than '[reach] stalemate'. You can use '[become] stalemated' as well as 'become a stalemate'.

Note that in chess, a stalemate means that the player whose turn it is cannot move at all. In eg football, political negotiations and war, things keep happening, although maybe slowly, and a stalemate can be broken by something extraordinary event.

Answer (score 0):

You could say:

The game/match *had become* a stalemate

The game/match *reached* a stalemate

The two teams reached a stalemate

Comment: So, this would be poorly [written](http://articles.orlandosentinel.com/2013-09-07/sports/os-hs-leesburg-eustis-0908-20130907_1_eustis-leesburg-yellow-jackets-jabari-dunham)? 
  
"Eustis (0-2) answered in the first half with an Andrew Holland-to-Thomas Stutts 25-yard touchdown pass, but the ****teams went into a stalemate*** after the early scoring."

Comment: I'm really not certain. It seems correct, but also seems wrong in some way, I'm not sure...